# Genus of the union of three complete graph each isomorphic to $K_5$.

Tags: graph-theory

> Suppose $G_1,G_2,G_3$ are three graphs each isomorphic to $K_5$. Suppose $V(G_1)=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, $V(G_2)=\{1,2,6,7,8\}$ and $V(G_3)=\{1,2,9,10,11\}$. What is the genus of the graph $G=G_1\cup G_2\cup G_3$?

I think it is $2$, but I can't prove it.

Comment: Have you drawn that graph on a genus 2 surface, and are wondering about the proof that genus 1 won't do, or what is your guess based on?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I have tried to draw the graph in the plain with at most two crossing, but so far not succeed. So my guest is a wild one. I know also that $1\leq \gamma(G)\leq 4$. So there are four possibilities.

Comment: @jyrkiLahtonen I have drawn the graph on the torus with one crossing. So genus of the graph is atmost 2